# Need Help about EaseUS LockMyFile

Tags: permissions, file-unlocking, locked-files

i just locked a folder with  EaseUS LockMyFile . every thing was ok at first  but  today  i just realized i can't open that  folder
even after giving password  correctly

every time  i tried its unlocking but then shows locked again looks like nothing happens

when i cheeked  program log say deny read

and when  checked folder permissions  says you do not have read permissions to view the properties of this object

i have really no idea why program can't open the folder that is lock by itself maybe because long  destination or something ? but in first days there was no problem  and this only happens to this folder

is there any way to remove or give  permissions  from like safe mod ? EaseUS gives so many tips about situation to how to unlock locked folder by windows   but nothing about  own app !

i send mail to  EaseUS support but not have any hope base my exp  supports are useless they just know to copy paste

Comment: If the claims by EaseUS are accurate then your files are encrypted. Since you didn’t use the built-in feature within Windows, only their tool can decrypt your files. If the tool is preventing that from happening then your files are permanently lost.

Answer (score 1):

See the EaseUS Support article
[How to Recover Files from Folder Lock Without Password Step-by-Step](https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/recover-files-from-folder-lock-without-password.html).

The article describes in great detail three possible methods.
Below is the summary of the proposed methods, but see the article
for much more detail and screenshots.

- Use the Serial Number that you used to register Folder Lock as the master key (if this option was selected during the installation and you received a serial number)
- Remove the password by uninstalling Folder Lock:

  - Use `regedit` to position to registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/NewSoftware's/Folder Lock/Uninstall` and set item `Uninstall` to `0`
  - Uninstall Folder Lock via *Settings > Apps > Apps & Features*
- Stop Folder Lock password protection :

  - Boot in Safe mode
  - Reinstall Folder Lock but don't click the Finish button
  - Right-click the locked folder, select Properties, Security tab
  - Uncheck all Deny boxes for all usernames on top and click OK
  - Now you might be able to access your files and copy them away.

Comment: thank you  so much but looks like this methods not worked this is for  old version

Comment: @Ramhound: These are not quotes. The article is much more wordy.

Comment: @Farzan: Unfortunately, these are the only known workarounds. If they no longer work, then I hope you have backup for these files.

Comment: oh no backup man its not encrypt method  just locked folder and after giving password correctly  nothing happens asks again    i have never seen any thing like that  instead of protection lost my data 

the thing is there no NewSoftware's in regedit even  looked for  EaseUS but nothing . its not works with new version  . i just don't know its good idea to uninstall or not

 tried safe mode but  even from there cant access permissions 

even if i can recover data still not have idea how can delete this folder 

windows says to get access you will need to use security tab

Comment: from security tab says you must have read  permission

Comment: The documentation mentions an unbreakable encryption method. It seems like you must do it through the application itself.